# Python: CodeAcademy: Classes

Tags: python, class

I am learning about classes with CodeAcademy (Python).

Here are the instructions:

Add a second member variable, health, to the Animal class, and set it equal to the string "good". Then, create two new Animals: sloth and ocelot. (Give them whatever names or ages you like.) Go ahead and print out your hippo's, sloth's, and ocelot's health.

---

Here is my code:

```
class Animal(object):
"""Makes cute animals."""
is_alive = True
health = "Good" 

def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age

def description(self):
    print self.name
    print self.age 
    print self.is_alive
    print self.health

hippo = Animal("Mary", 02)
sloth = Animal("Larry", 03)
ocelot = Animal("Karry", 04)

hippo.description()
sloth.description()
ocelot.description()
```

---

Code Academy returns:

"Oops, try again. It looks like your three animals don't all have a health of "good"."

---

However, when I enter the code "Good" is printed for all of them. It looks like this:

Mary
2
True
Good
Larry
3
True
Good
Karry
4
True
Good

---

What is the error that CodeAcademy is describing? Any help or suggestions are appreciated during this learning process.

Thank you advance.

Comment: It says to set it to `good` (lower case g) - you've got: `health = "Good"`.... Would you mind providing a link to this example on CodeAcademy...

Comment: http://www.codecademy.com/courses/python-intermediate-en-WL8e4/1/4?curriculum_id=4f89dab3d788890003000096

Comment: CodeAcademy is very good (;)) but one of its drawbacks is that it interprets the output very literally. So @JonClements above is right. Also, from my experience it's a very common problem beginners have with these tutorials. On the other hand - in programming every detail matters, so maybe it's not a drawback after all and it teaches a very good lesson about paying attention to details.

Comment: Yes, that was the mistake! I didn't think it mattered. Thank you @JonClements

Comment: As a curiosity, I'm facing problems on Codecademy where it isn't letting me do the Python tutorials. It keeps giving me "failed to connect" warnings; Do you have any workarounds for this that allow you to do the courses, @user3055848?

Answer (score 0):

You capitalized the first letter: "Good".
Try "good".

Also, you are setting a class variable, in the class scope. In Python, you want to set `self.health = "good"` for a member variable. If you define variables under `class Class`, they will be in class scope and be global across instances.

Answer (score 0):

I have finished Codecedemy, this is my code.

```
class Animal(object):
"""Makes cute animals."""
    is_alive = True
    health = "good"
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        # Add your method here!
    def description(self):
        print self.name
        print self.age       
hippo = Animal("Bob",100)
sloth = Animal("Sam", 1000000)
ocelot = Animal("Katherine", 3)
print hippo.is_alive, hippo.description
print hippo.health
print sloth.health
print ocelot.health
```